# Nested Form: find_or_create_by multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, nested-forms

I'm stuck in the middle of a nested form and usage of active records "find_or_create_by" method.. What I'm trying to do:

I have 3 models: Account, Transaction and Category.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :categories, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
  belongs_to :account
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :category, :autosave => true
  belongs_to :account

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category
end
```

My form looks like this: app/views/transactions/new.haml

```
= semantic_form_for @transaction do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :account_id, :as => :hidden
    = f.input :title, :label => false
    = f.input :amount, :label => false
    = f.inputs :for => :category do |c|
      = c.input :title, :as => :string
      = c.input :account_id, :as => :hidden
  = f.buttons do
    = f.submit "Save"
```

My controllers look like this:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new
    @transaction.date ||= Transaction.last.date if Transaction.last
    @transaction.account= Account.find(params[:account]) if params[:account]
    @account = @last_transaction.account if @last_transaction
    @account = Account.find(params[:account]) if params[:account]
    @transaction.build_category(:account => @account)
  end

  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new(params[:transaction])
    @account = @transaction.account
    respond_to do |format|
      if @transaction.save
         format.html {redirect_to (new_transaction_path( :account => @account ))}
      else
         format.html {redirect_to (new_transaction_path( :account => @account ))}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Categories Controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @category = Category.new
    @category.account = Account.find(params[:account]) if params[:account]
    @accounts = current_user.accounts
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html {redirect_to (categories_path)}
      else
        format.html {render :action => "new"}
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])
        format.html {redirect_to (categories_path)}
      else
        format.html {render :action => "edit"}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I'm stuck. I only want to create a new category, if there isn't already an existing category with the same title AND same account_id.

By now, it always creates a new category, ignoring that there is already a category with the same name and the same account_id. I know that I should use something like this:

```
Category.find_or_create_by_title_and_account_id(category.title, account.id)
```

But where should I use it and how should it look exactly?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: so where is your controller code?

Comment: I added controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Category.find_or_initialize_by_title_and_account_id(category.title, account.id)`, then modify it and save (`_create_` saves the object in the same line). But if I understand correctly, what you need here are [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html). By convention, we design our apps to retrieve errors (like: "Category title must be unique") in `#create` actions of your controllers and if there are errors, we `render :action => :new` again (with the same form as previously, but with errors shown). I see that you're using formtastic, so you've got errors display in forms by default (I think).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But where would i place your suggested line? Which controller and which action?

Comment: You have it in your controller because that's the usual and most appropriate way. I see some problems with your code, have you read rails guides? And where's definition of `@last_transaction` in your controller?

Comment: Can you try replacing `@transaction.build_category(:account => @account)` with `@transaction.category = Category.find_or_initialize_by_account_id_and_transaction_id(@account.id, @transaction.id)`